# How do I break my For loop if an error is returned

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have to break sqlcmd batch command when any error occur in `.sql` scripts in a folder of one or more `.sql` script files.

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd -b /S "ServerInstance" /d "DBName" -U "Username" -P "Password" -i "%%G"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 EXIT /b
```

This command executes all files in folder one by one (in sequence)
I have two `.sql` script files in my folder; first script return error in execution thats where I want to break the execution, but it does not break and continue execution of second script in the folder.

Comment: You are using an errorlevel statement after the loop, not during it!

Comment: I'd try this: `for %%G in ("*.sql") do sqlcmd -b /S "ServerInstance" /d "DBName" -U "Username" -P "Password" -i "%%~G" || exit /B` (the `||` is a [conditional command concatenation operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which lets the following command execute only when the preceding one failed)

Comment: I'm with @aschipfl but prefer to name it [conditional execution](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) Never saw it named `conditional command concatenation operator`

Comment: Well, @LotPings, conditional execution is the result of using this operator... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `if %ErrorLevel%==1` query after the loop, this is of course not exited.

Moving it into the loop would solve your problem, although I would not check `ErrorLevel` for `1`, I would rather check it against not being `0`:

```cmd
for %%G in (*.sql) do (
    sqlcmd -b /S "ServerInstance" /d "DBName" -U "Username" -P "Password" -i "%%~G"
    if not ErrorLevel 1 exit /B
)
```

This would exit the loop if an `ErrorLevel` value of `1` or greater is encountered, so it is expected that your command does not produce a negative value. (A nice side effect of this syntax is that it does not require [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which would be required for a condition like `if !ErrorLevel! neq 0`.)

---

An even better and simpler approach is to use the [conditional execution operator `||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which checks the exit code of the preceding command (which is in most cases the same as `ErrorLevel`) and executes the following one only in case of a non-zero value:

```cmd
for %%G in (*.sql) do (
    sqlcmd -b /S "ServerInstance" /d "DBName" -U "Username" -P "Password" -i "%%~G" || exit /B
)
```